# SQL Order by 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

Let's say that I have a database, that looks like that:

```
price      date       hour
12.00    2018-12-11    5
13.00    2018-12-04    2
14.00    2018-12-06    1 
15.00    2018-12-11    1
16.00    2018-12-04    6
17.00    2018-12-06    10
```

I need to order by date and if days are the same after hour, so results should be:

```
   price      date       hour
    13.00    2018-12-04    2
    16.00    2018-12-04    6
    14.00    2018-12-06    1
    17.00    2018-12-06    10
    15.00    2018-12-11    1
    12.00    2018-12-11    5
```

I tried to write a simple query, but it couldn't take into account 2 conditions, one after another:

```
SELECT price, date, hour
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-04' AND '2018-12-11'
ORDER BY date, hour
```

Could anyone help with this issue ?

Thanks All !

Comment: Your query should do exactly what you want.  What are you getting?

Comment: What are the table column data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real issue I can think of would be if `hour` were stored as a string.  If so, use implicit conversion:

```
SELECT price, date, hour
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-04' AND '2018-12-11'
ORDER BY date, hour + 0;
```

Comment: Although implicit conversion during the ORDER BY may work, it is less readable and slightly less efficient. You are better off to explicitly declare the `hour` column as a TINYINT.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `ORDER BY` will suffice:

```
select * from my_table order by `date`, hour;
```

Please note the `date` is usually a reserved word, so its usage is discouraged, and needs to be quoted.